# Allow-Control-Allow-Origin in a specific controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, ionic-framework

I got an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error in a specific request, but the controller was built following the same logic of another controllers, where this error doesn't occurrs.

**Request Headers with Acces-Control-Allow-Origin**

[image]

**Request Headers without Acces-Control-Allow-Origin**

[image]

**JS**

```
function MyGoalsCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        var responsePromise = $http.get("http://localhost:57907/api/Meta/GetListMetas");

        responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {                
            $scope.metas = data;
        });
        responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("AJAX failed!");
        });
    }; 
}

function TeamGoalsCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loadMore = function () {       
        var responsePromise = $http.get("http://localhost:57907/api/MetaTime/GetListMetasTime");

        responsePromise.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {                            
            $scope.metas = data;
        });

        responsePromise.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("AJAX failed!");
        });
    };    
}

angular
    .module('starter.controllers')
    .controller('MyGoalsCtrl', MyGoalsCtrl)
    .controller('TeamGoalsCtrl', TeamGoalsCtrl);
```

**Web API MetaController used in MyGoalsCtrl**

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class MetaController : ApiController
{
    public FastGoalDataStructure GetListMetas()
    {            
        var metas = GoalDataSingleton.Instance.GoalData;
        return metas;
    }
}
```

**Web API MetaController used in TeamGoalsCtrl**

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class MetaTimeController : ApiController
{
    public FastGoalDataStructure GetListMetasTime()
    {
        var metas = SelectAreaMembers();
        return metas;
    }
}
```

**My Web API Config**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I did something wrong or missing something ?

Comment: did you `config.EnableCors();`? http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: @KhanhTO yes, but just the MetaTimeController don't work

Comment: You're getting a `500 Internal Server Error`, thus not getting the response back from the controller which has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.  Figure out what's causing the 500 error and you'll get the correct response back

Comment: As Tom said, check the console in chrome to see what response came back or debug the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MetaTimeController.GetListMetasTime()`  is returning a `500 Internal Server Error`, thus, you're not even getting back the response that you're expecting.

Look at the body of the response, if it was simply not adding the CORS header, you'd still see the correct data; however, yours will say there was an error.  Your controller isn't even getting a chance to add the header, because it's erroring out.

Figure out what is causing the error in your server, and, once you're able to return a `200 OK` response, you will notice the header is working.

Comment: You're right, I made a clone from the MetaController and put in MetaTimeController, and works, so the problem are in MetaTimeController logic, like you said. Thanks